# Win7 create a shortcut to open FTP in explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, shortcuts

If I create a shortcut with this "ftp://x.x.x.x", it will open default browser and go to that ftp. Is there any way to let the shortcut open that FTP in explorer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect to an FTP site in Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/88531/how-do-i-connect-to-an-ftp-site-in-windows-explorer)

Comment: Use this shortcut ```%windir%\explorer ftp://UserName:UserPassW@ftp.yoursite.com```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are the steps to map the FTP site as a drive on your computer which in turn can be opened with Windows Explorer.

1. Open the **Control Panel** and go to **Internet Options**
2. Go to the **Advanced** tab and under Browsing make sure that **Enable FTP folder view (outside of Internet Explorer)**
3. Scroll down to **Use Passive FTP (for Firewall and DSL modem compatibility.)** and make sure that it's checked.
4. Go to **Computer** and at the top click **Map Network Drive**
5. Type in the address of the FTP site
6. Type in the login credentials
7. You should now be able to access that FTP as a drive within Windows Explorer

**Note: If there are any mistakes in my post, please edit them accordingly.*

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel > Folder Options
File Types Tab

Extension: (NONE), File Types: URL: File Transfer Protocol
"Advanced"

Actions: open
"Edit..."

Application used to perform action:

Change that part, and "Application" to use Internet Explorer (iexplore.exe) instead.

Comment: unfortunately Windows 7 doesn't have File Type Tab in Folder Options.

Comment: @Stan Ah really? I'm on an XP box right now. There should be an equivalent somewhere.