# How to connect to a remote server to make instant file edits?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, ftp, website, web-hosting

I don't know what the technical term for this is, but at my workplace every computer has a mapped network drive which lets me access all files on the server which I believe is located in the same building.

I am able to make edits to any file on the server and the changes will be instant. For example I can open up a text file located on the server in a text editor, and when I hit save the changes are live on the server. No need to transfer the new file onto the server via FTP or something.

The live file editing is what I hope to achieve with the webhost of my personal website, if this is even possible. Right now I have to use FTP to make changes to the live site.

I'm using Vista Home Basic.

Comment: This is called a network share FYI Why not map the FTP server as a network drive? Also the webmasters Se might be able to assist as it's closer to their field of expertise

Comment: I think I tried that, I opened Computer and entered into the bar ftp : // username:password@hostname and I was able to connect to it, but it wouldn't allow me to make file edits without downloading the file first. It was pretty much another FileZilla.

Comment: Read the answer with the most up votes http://superuser.com/questions/88531/how-do-i-connect-to-ftp-site-in-windows-explorer

Answer (score 0):

theres a app called netdrive that lets you do this
http://lifehacker.com/300997/mount-remote-file-systems-with-netdrive
i've never used it personally but i trust lifehacker reviews to only suggest it if its good

> Mount remote drives over FTP, SFTP, WebDAV or iFolder to your desktop
>   with freeware application NetDrive. Once mounted, you can navigate
>   your remote drive like any other folder in Windows Explorer. The
>   application is free to download, but its development has been
>   discontinued so it's somewhat hard to come by (hence the direct
>   download link below). But you can still access advanced user
>   instructions from Novell. I actually had major problems with NetDrive
>   crashing Explorer after I connected, but the folks at weblog
>   FreewareGenius had nothing but success with NetDrive, so your mileage
>   may vary. NetDrive is a free download, Windows only. Mac users can
>   achieve the same thing with previously mentioned MacFusion. If you
>   know of an alternate solution, let's hear it in the comments.